# Maven project duplicate dependencies warnings

Tags: maven-3

I have started a new project trying to work with Maven. I get the following warnings.

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for services.cryptoconsultant.dev.torreapp:torrefind-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 60, column 19
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 70, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

I have not modified anything myself, so I guess this relates to?

Comment: First format the output better otherwise it's hard to read...apart from that it tells you the problem? and without a pom file it impossible to help...

Comment: @khmarbaise The formatting is done automatically. I do not know how to override this behavior.
I will see what I can do with the pom file.

Comment: No if you enter it correctly it is not...

Comment: Read the help about formatting and editing post...

Comment: @khmarbaise I will try to read that. However, I am not convinced that your editing made it more readable though. Having to scroll all the way to the end, is at least controversial.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Now you could insert line break where you like...